# Trying to build polygon from NSString

Tags: objective-c, arrays, polygon, cgpoint, polygons

So, I'm trying to build an array of CGPoints by breaking an NSString, typically look like this:

```
31.241854,34.788867;31.241716,34.788744;31.242547,34.787585;31.242661,34.787719
```

Using this code:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)buildPolygon:(NSString *)polygon
{
    NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [stringArray addObject:[polygon componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];
    NSMutableArray *polygonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i < polygonArray.count; i++)
    {
        NSArray *polygonStringArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
        polygonStringArray = [[stringArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        CGFloat xCord = [[polygonStringArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
        CGFloat yCord = [[polygonStringArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue];
        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(xCord, yCord);
        [polygonArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
    }

    NSLog(@"return polygonArray: %@", polygonArray);
    return polygonArray;
}
```

But eventually I get an empty array.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked all the intermediate steps, i.e., that the earlier arrays are valid and what you expect? For example, what's `[stringArray objectAtIndex:1]`? (Hint: You've only put one object in there.) What are the possible values of `i` anyways?

Comment: Before the 'if' i had a log, and the plot was: (
        (
        "31.241854,34.788867",
        "31.241716,34.788744",
        "31.242547,34.787585",
        "31.242661,34.787719"
    ). Mean this was ok, but 'polygonArray' is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining `polygonArray` as an empty array just before the start of your for loop.  You should define `polygonArray` like:

```
NSArray *polygonArray = [polygon componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

And you don't even need to bother with that `stringArray` variable.

Comment: Sorry this is wrong, `polygonArray` is declared correctly, it is the result array... You've been misled by the typo in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You have confusion over `alloc` & `init`, and one simple typo...

The confusions first:

```
NSMutableArray *stringArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This creates a new `NSMutableArray` and stores a reference to it in `stringArray`. All good so far.

```
[stringArray addObject:[polygon componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];
```

And this obtains a reference to an `NSArray` (`[polygon componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]`) and adds it as a *single element* to the mutable array referenced by `stringArray`. There is nothing wrong *per se* with this, but it is *not* what you want in this case - you just want the array returned by `componentsSeparatedByString:`. You do this with:

```
NSArray *stringArray = [polygon componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

Which takes the reference returned by `componentsSeparatedByString:` and stores it in the variable `stringArray` - no `alloc` or `init` required as you are not creating the array yourself. You don't even *own* this array, so if you are using MRC there is no need to `release` it later.

```
NSArray *polygonStringArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

Now this allocates an *immutable* empty array and stores a reference to it in `polygonStringArray`. *This is not a very useful array, as it contains nothing and cannot be modified!* But you don't keep it around long...

```
polygonStringArray = [[stringArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

This obtains a reference to an array from `componentsSeparatedByString:` and stores it in `polygonStringArray`. If you are using MRC this will cause a **leak** - your pointless zero-length array created above will leak, and a new zero-length array will be created and leaked every time around the loop.

You are confused over allocation - you only need to allocate things you are creating; when you receive a reference to an already allocated object you only need to store that reference. (If using MRC you may also need to retain/release/autorelease it as well - but let's stick with ARC.) So all you needed here was:

```
NSArray *polygonStringArray = [[stringArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Now your code is almost correct, just one typo:

```
for (int i=0; i < polygonArray.count; i++)
```

Well you are filling `polygonArray` in this loop and it starts off as empty, what you need is `stringArray.count`.

HTH